# Solve for p of Binomial distribution

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

Is there a way to solve for the probability p of a binomial distribution in a set of equations? With some arbitrary functions g[ _ ] and f[ _ ] such that:

```
eq1 = -g[y] + Sqrt[g[y]^2 + 4*5*5/200] (200^2/2*5) - x
eq2 := Sum[PDF[BinomialDistribution[15, y], i]*f [i], {i, 0, 15}] - 10*x
bif = NSolve[eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, {x, y}]
```

I even simplified it to:

```
f[x_] := 0.34*Exp[-150*x]

eq1 := Sum[
   Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], x]*f[x], {x, 0, 15}] - 10
bif = NSolve[eq1 == 0, {y}]
```

However the output I get is:

```
NSolve[-10 + 
   2.43953*10^-66 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 0] + 
   0.337692 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 1] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 2] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 3] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 4] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 5] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 6] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 7] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 8] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 9] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 10] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 11] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 12] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 13] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 14] + 
   0.34 Probability[BinomialDistribution[15, y], 15] == 0, {y}]
```

Effectively it is just solving this coupled system of equations. However, Mathematica does not provide a solution when I use the binomial function. The exact parameters don't matter, it's more a general question on how to solve these types of problems.
I hope you can help :)

(Mathematica newbie here)

Comment: Try `NSolve~ or `FindRoot`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I think you need to change `PDF[Binomial[15, y], i]` to `PDF[BinomialDistribution[15, y], i]`.  You can solve for `x` in both equations and then solve for `y` but solving for `y` probably requires knowing $g$ and/or $f$.

Comment: You need to change `Probability` to `PDF`.

Comment: I suspect you need the restriction $0<y\leq 1$ but if you plot `eq1` (from your simplified example), there is no value of $y$ in that range where `eq1==0`.

Comment: For values $0<y<1$ in `eq1` you have a set of 16 probabilities (that sum to one) multiplied by a function that's very much less than 1 so that the sum has to be less than 1 and subtracting 10 from that will not get `eq1==1`.  You need a better example.

Answer (score 4):

Try first the simpler problem: solve for p, for example

```
NSolve[CDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], 35] == 0.025, p] // Quiet
```

The solution is obtained right away  {{p -> 0.821382}}